# Are Manfrotto tripod bases for video compatible with the photo line of heads?

Tags: tripod, tripod-heads, manfrotto

I'm looking to purchase a tripod setup. I'm looking at the Manfrotto line of products. Does anyone know if the video line of bases is compatible with photo line of heads? Specifically, the 546B base and the 400DXL head. I will probably buy a couple of bases but I would like cross-compatibility across everything I buy. I'm looking at the 546B because it suppose up to 44 lbs. I would look for info on the manfrotto website, but it appears to be down at the moment.

Comment: BTW, Manfrotto has one site for most country, so while .com is down, .ca is not. You may need [this one](http://www.manfrotto.ca/product/0/520BALL/_/75mm_Half_Ball_Leveler_with_38%27%27_Screw_for_75mm_Bowl_Tripods) or a 1/4" version, depending on the 400DXL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a part. The one that goes between the head and tripod. All you need is to by the one that makes the connection possible.

Most heads use either a 3/8" or 1/4" thread. You have to check with the 400DXL because I've never seen one. The 546B uses a 75mm fitting, so you need to find one of those with the thread for your head. If you buy multiple items, it is easiest to have everything with the same thread-size but, fear not, small adapters exist to make a 1/4" screw into a 3/8" one.

Comment: Said 1/4 to 3/8 adaptors are also very inexpensive. Well under $10, maybe even under $2.

Comment: How does the head connect to the base? What is this 75 mm bowl on teh video base? I think this plays into @Itai comment above about an adapter.

Comment: @JMD Not sure which part of my answer is not clear. The need a *bowl* between the legs and the head. That one has a thread which screws into the head. If it matches perfectly, that is all you need. If the screw on the bowl is too small, you can get a cheap adapter to make the screw wider. There are only two sizes of screws, so most likely it fits without adapter.